# crear columnas en base a checkbox seleccionados en js con jquey

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy intentando hacer una tabla dinamica en `html` con `js` y `jquery`,mi idea es que cuando el usuario seleccione algunos checkbox y presione el boton submit,se cree una tabla y el numero de columnas que se creen dependa del numero de checkbox que se seleccionaron,y el nombre de cada columna tenga el nombre de cada checkbox que se selecciono,he estado intentando hacerlo pero no he tenido exito,adjunto codigo para mostrar lo que intento hacer,alguien podria guiarme sobre como lo podria hacer?,desde ya muchas gracias!!!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>creat tablas</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form name="myform" id="myform"> 
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='1'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA1</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='2'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA2</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='3'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA3</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='4'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA4</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='5'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA5</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='6'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA6</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='7'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA7</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='8'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA8</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='9'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA9</label></li>      
<table id="tabla1">
            <tr id="Row2">
                
            </tr>
        </table>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>



<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('submit', '#myform', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var checkbox = $('[name^="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
                 return $(this).val();
                }).get();
                console.log(checkbox.length)
        
        
               for (var i = 0; i >= checkbox.length; i++) {
               $("#tabla1 tr").each(function(){        
               $(this).append("<td>"+checkbox[i] +"</td>");
              
             
                }) 
           }   
                
 });
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu código estás obteniendo solo los valores de los *checkbox*, en caso de funcionar, solo te agregaría el número y no el texto de la etiqueta a cada celda.

Cuando intentas agregar la celda, lo haces con [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/), que requiere un nodo y tú estás enviando código HTML.

Para que funcione como esperas:

- Carga en una variable todos los *checkbox* marcados, no solo sus valores
- Crea una variable obtener código inicial HTML de la fila
- Recorre cada checkbox usando [`$.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function)
- Dentro de la función obtienes la etiqueta y concatenas el HTML de una celda a la variable
- Al salir del ciclo solo asignas el HTML a la fila y *¡voilà, funciona!*

Agrega las celdas que necesitas por defecto y asigna una clase para saber que no se deben borrar.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('submit', '#myform', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Obtener checkboxes marcados
        var checkbox = $('[name^="checkbox"]:checked');
        // Eliminar celdas que no tengan clase "default"
        $.each($("#Row2 td"), (index, td) => {
            if(!$(td).hasClass('default')) {
                $(td).remove();
            }
        });
        // Inicializar contenido
        let html = $("#Row2").html();
        // Recorrer checkboxes
        $.each(checkbox, (index, chk) => {
            // Buscar etiqueta asociada y obtener texto
            let label = $(chk).parent().find('label').text();
            // Crear celda
            html += `<td>${label}</td>`;
        });
        // Asignar HTML a fila de tabla
        $("#Row2").html(html);
    });
});
```

```css
table td {
    border:1px #777 solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myform" id="myform"> 
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='1'><label for="text1">PRUEBA1</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='2'><label for="text1">PRUEBA2</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='3'><label for="text1">PRUEBA3</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='4'><label for="text1">PRUEBA4</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='5'><label for="text1">PRUEBA5</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='6'><label for="text1">PRUEBA6</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='7'><label for="text1">PRUEBA7</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='8'><label for="text1">PRUEBA8</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='9'><label for="text1">PRUEBA9</label></li>      
<table id="tabla1">
            <tr id="Row2">
                <td class="default">Esta no se borra</td>
                <td class="default">Esta tampoco</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: me funcion perfecto,solo que tengo una  duda,si tuviera dos columnas que  tienen que estar en la tabla por default como lo podria hacer???

Comment: Listo, revisa la actualización. Siempre que hagas una pregunta, recuerda incluir todos los datos relevantes.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda lo tomare en cuenta!!

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el valor de tus checkbox y así agregar los seleccionados a una tabla de manera dinámica necesitas obtener el valor de cada uno. Te comparto una solución si no quieres utilizar jQuery.

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('#checkbox');
let header = document.querySelector('#headers');

function createTable() {
    checkbox.forEach(check => {
        if(check.checked) {
            let row = document.createElement('th');
            row.appendChild(
              document.createTextNode('PRUEBA'+check.value)
            );
            header.appendChild(row);
        }
    });
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" id="myform"> 
    <li><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='1'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA1</label></li>
    <li><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='2'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA2</label></li>
    <li><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='3'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA3</label></li>
    <li><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='4'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA4</label></li>
    <li><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='5'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA5</label></li>
    <li><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='6'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA6</label></li>
    <li><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='7'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA7</label></li>
    <li><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='8'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA8</label></li>
    <li><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='9'/><label for="text1">PRUEBA9</label></li>      
    <table id="tabla1">
      <thead>
        <tr id="headers">

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="createTable();">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Sin usar jQuery es una buena respuesta, solo tiene un error, antes de comenzar a agregar celdas, hay que eliminar las que ya existen, para evitar duplicados y se muestren siempre en el orden correcto.

Comment: Muy cierto, no había considerado ese caso. ¡Gracias por tu comentario!